# Warn if missing required informtion when passing Textbox entry to cell

Tags: excel, vba, textbox, msgbox

I have a UserForm in Excel 16 that enters text from TextBox5 into cell `Sheet1.Range("F2")` when CommandButton1 is pressed.

I have default text in the box that says "End miles" in the TextBox.

I want to pop a message box up telling the user to enter their ending mileage in the box when they click the CommandButton without putting it in.

This is the relevant codes I am using now:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
     If Not Range("F2").Text = "" Then TextBox5.Text = Range("F2").Text _
           Else TextBox5.Text = "End Miles"
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Sheet1.Range("F2") = TextBox5.Text
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

I'm trying:

```
If Not TextBox5.Text = "End Miles" Then 
     MsgBox "Enter ending mileage" 
Else 
     Sheet1.Range("F2") = TextBox5.Text
End If
```

Comment: Don't you want a msgbox when the text *is* "End miles", not when it's *not* End miles ?

Comment: I'm trying to warn the user that they have not changed the default "Enter ending mileage" has not been changed to their actual ending mileage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is reversed:

```
If TextBox5.Text = "End Miles" Then 
     MsgBox "Enter ending mileage" 
Else 
     Sheet1.Range("F2") = TextBox5.Text
End If
```

Comment: I can't believe how easy you made that look. Thank you!